# How to reference correct sender and recipient when loading Firestore Message

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this example for chatrooms  in my firebase chat application which follows:

```
let messageRef = db
    .collection("channels").document("UID1")
    .collection("threads").document("message1")
```

[image]

But if I do this method I don't see how I could find which user is associated with a chatroom because I would make each "roomA"/UID.
But how can I get that same "roomA"/UID to reference for the recipient to save the message to the same location?

Comment: Do you want the user who wrote the message or all users in the chatroom?

Comment: @DanFein i want to be able to get the both the sender and recipient users BUT i dont see how i could save those 2 users chat room info in the same room since the document that comes after ```.collection("rooms") ``` is an autogenerated ID from Firebase.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your database structure?

Comment: Yes please, a diagram of your structure would be really helpful. Hard to tell what you have, where the data is, and what you're not able to get from what we can see so far.

Comment: i added a pic @DanFein

Comment: is there a firestore data structure u recommend that supports a chatvc 1-1 messaging and a messagesvc - which just has the contacts the person has messaged?

Comment: where are the users? the senders/recipients

Comment: For each message, why don't you just store who sent it? createdBy = user, and in the main "channels/UID1" document you can store the users in the chat room?

Comment: @DanFein ight i get u but if the sender sends the message and we get a channels/UID1 how does the recipient get the correct UID1 to reference to save their message to the same thread and also how to know what channels UIDs belong to which user?

Comment: I would store users in the users collection, their ID in the relevant channels docs, and then also store their ID with the message itself.

Comment: @DanFein could u provide a image or a layout?

Comment: Sure I've just submitted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store users in a user collection, then store their user ID in a channels document, and then also store their ID with the message itself.

This might look like this:

```
Users (collection)
--- User1 (doc)

Channels (collection)
--- Channel1 (doc)
------ UsersInRoom (field within the user doc)
----------- ['User1', 'User2', 'User3']
--- Channel2
------ UsersInRoom
----------- ['User4', 'User5', 'User6']

--- Threads (collection within Channels collection)
------ Message1 (doc)
---------- Sender: User1
---------- Text: "Hi"
------ Message1 (doc)
---------- Sender: User2
---------- Text: "Hello"
```

With this structure you're making all messages easily accessible, you can quickly query the channel, the channel's threads, for any message you can see who the sender is, etc.